# Saving pictures to parse

Tags: ios, camera, parse-platform

My project will save data to parse and while I can pick an image from my library I cannot open the camera. I found a tutorial to do this but it is not compatible with my code. The link to the tutorial is here: [Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-camera-iphone-app/)   . I am using .storyboard and the tutorial is .xib, I do not know if this will change anything.

my .m file is here:

```
#import "NewRecipeViewController.h"
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"

@interface NewRecipeViewController ()
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *recipeImageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *prepTimeTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *ingredientsTextField;

@end

@implementation NewRecipeViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _nameTextField.delegate = self;
    _prepTimeTextField.delegate = self;
    _ingredientsTextField.delegate = self;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        [self showPhotoLibary];
    }
}


- (void)showPhotoLibary
{
    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
          UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum] == NO)) {
        return;
    }

    UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    mediaUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    // Displays saved pictures from the Camera Roll album.
    mediaUI.mediaTypes = @[(NSString*)kUTTypeImage];

    // Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures
    mediaUI.allowsEditing = NO;

    mediaUI.delegate = self;

    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController: mediaUI animated: YES];
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    // Create PFObject with recipe information
    PFObject *recipe = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Recipe"];
    [recipe setObject:_nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];
    [recipe setObject:_prepTimeTextField.text forKey:@"prepTime"];

    NSArray *ingredients = [_ingredientsTextField.text componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
    [recipe setObject:ingredients forKey:@"ingredients"];

    // Recipe image
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_recipeImageView.image, 0.8);
    NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", _nameTextField.text];
    PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:filename data:imageData];
    [recipe setObject:imageFile forKey:@"imageFile"];

    // Show progress
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    hud.labelText = @"Uploading";
    [hud show:YES];

    // Upload recipe to Parse
    [recipe saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        [hud hide:YES];

        if (!error) {
            // Show success message
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Upload Complete" message:@"Successfully saved the recipe" delegate:Nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];

            // Notify table view to reload the recipes from Parse cloud
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refreshTable" object:self];

            // Dismiss the controller
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        } else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Upload Failure" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];

        }

    }];
}

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setRecipeImageView:nil];
    [self setNameTextField:nil];
    [self setPrepTimeTextField:nil];
    [self setIngredientsTextField:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}


- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {

    UIImage *originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    self.recipeImageView.image = originalImage;

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}

#pragma mark - Textfield delegate

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction)takephoto:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (IBAction)selectphoto:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
@end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Apple's provided sample project (especially APLViewController.m)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196

You'll see them do the following 4 steps. You are only doing the last half of step one, without first verifying if that source type is even available.

From the UIImagePickerController Class Reference:

> To use an image picker controller containing its default controls, perform these steps:

```
Verify that the device is capable of picking content from the desired source. Do this calling the isSourceTypeAvailable: class method, providing a constant from the “UIImagePickerControllerSourceType” enumeration.

Check which media types are available, for the source type you’re using, by calling the availableMediaTypesForSourceType: class method. This lets you distinguish between a camera that can be used for video recording and one that can be used only for still images.

Tell the image picker controller to adjust the UI according to the media types you want to make available—still images, movies, or both—by setting the mediaTypes property.

Present the user interface. On iPhone or iPod touch, do this modally (full-screen) by calling the presentViewController:animated:completion: method of the currently active view controller, passing your configured image picker controller as the new view controller.
```